# IP Adress is 10.0.2.15 and need to acces via browser

Tags: 12.04, server

For school I have to set up an Ubuntu server, I have no clue what to do so I found a guide which I can follow. The problem is that on the video he gets a normal IP-address and can access it with his browser, but I am getting a private IP address and I have no clue how to change it. The Ip-address I get is `10.0.2.15`.

edit: it is a server in virtual machine

Comment: why you need to access it by browser?

Comment: Because eventually I'm going to have to put a website on it

Comment: did you install Apache ?

Comment: if not tell me to help you

Comment: I did not install Apache yet, but I have to go somewhere now. When I get back I'm going to follow the tutorial and see if they install it and then i'll see if it works

Comment: Address is also private ip address. Can you give me your ip, netmask and gw? Server and you workstation is in the same lan or not? If you wish access you web server via internet you must do port forwarding on school router witch is connected to internet

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to mention that the server is actually in virtualbox, ip: 10.0.2.15, Mask: 255.255.255.0 , and I don't know what you mean by gw

Comment: what do you mean by private ip ?

Comment: idk, I looked it up what it means and all I could find was that it's a private ip :s. I have no knowledge of servers whatsoever and this is the first time I'm working with Ubuntu too.

Comment: You need to setup network access between your regular OS and VirtualBox to get thsi to work, which is a VirtualBox question rather than an Ubuntu one. However I don't really understand the point because you might as well go to `http://localhost` within the virtual machine, and you'd get the web server result right there.

Comment: Don't ask on more than SE site at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Install Apache :

```
sudo apt-get install apache
```

Place your work in `/var/www`

Now you can access the from browser by typing ip or by localhost .

To start or stop service :

```
sudo service apache2 start

sudo service apache2 stop
```

Now you can just access the locally or by local network not by Internet .

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the address, resolving name to ip numbers is a system which is not affected by which number you are using.
If the school did not ask you to address the server by a specified name you can just use`http://10.0.2.15` in your browser.

Else a quick way which only works for the computer at which you are sitting is to add the ip to the hosts file. So add

```
10.0.2.15 www.something.org
```

to the file `/etc/hosts`. Now you can access the server with `http://www.something.org`
(after you have installed apache)

Comment: he want to build a web server , and want to access it

Comment: Then he should alter his question, he asks how to change ip to access via a browser.